# Asynchronous function 'post-cleanup'

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have this kind of setup: I'm trying to use custom event-handlers for processing a `.data` hash and to 'garbage collect' it's items after handlers had run, to avoid keeping them needlessly in memory, etc. `.defer()` function simulates what I got, it generates functions based on provided ones that run asynchronously, trying to mimic native event-handling that way...

Thing that confuses me is that deleting data items, by assigning `... = null;`, after calling deferred function seems to run before a function gets executed, basically inverting execution order(?!), leaving a function with no data to work with...

Here's the script I have:

```
  //
  //
  var defer = function(func) {

    // get asynchronoused `.func()` version
    return function() {

      // cache inputs for use by defered function
      var args = arguments;
      var node = this;

      return setTimeout(
        function() {
          func.apply(node, args);
        }
      ), node;

    };
  };


  var action = function(node) {
    // process a node
    console.log(node['@foo']['txt']);
  };


  var data = {

    '@foo': {
      'id'  : '#foo',
      'tag' : 'h2',
      'txt' : 'stuff',
    },

    '@spam': {
      'id'  : '#spam',
      'tag' : 'h1',
      'txt' : 'and shit',
    },
  };

  // run `.action()` asynchronously
  defer(action)(data);

  // garbage collect after
  data['@foo'] = null;
  // this part seems to run before function call
  // cleaning the data before `defer(action)(data);` gets it's time
  // it throws error here because `null` gc-ed it right away (or something)
  //   TypeError: node['@foo'] is null
  //
```

---

I'm currently working around the issue by providing additional function (`_finaly()`) to callbacks that will run the cleanup right after data get processed, which seems quite awkward and unnatural to simple thing.. Question is why the piece code of seems to run out of order and **what is exactly going on here or is there a cleaner way to work around the issue**?

Here's the solution i've got so far:

```
  var action = function(node, _finaly) {
    // provide `._finaly()` callback 
    // that will run after processing gets done
    /////

    console.log(node['@foo']['txt']);

    // .. and run the cleanup code
    _finaly && _finaly(node, 'txt');

  };

  defer(action)(data, function (node, item) {
    // do the house-keep in a callback here
    // rather than directly after execution
    node.hasOwnProperty(item) && (node[item] = null);
  });
  //
  // eof
```

Comment: It runs out of "order" because it is *asynchronous*!

Comment: Yes, your solution with the other callback is basically the way to go. You might not even modify `action`, but simply wrap it (as it's synchronous on itself), and maybe use some other higher-order functions to get nicer-looking code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as Bergi said, the behaviour you observe is what to be expected. The main call stack is always finished before any asynchronous call starts. If you had more than 1 call to `defer` you would not even know which one would execute first.

Why don't you just clean your array in the `action` function call? I understand that it may break the logic of implementation and is not always feasible. If so, you may want to use native events instead. For example, using the [MutationObserver](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/) could be a fun idea in this case.

1. Observe a hidden `DOMElement` of your choice
2. When you're done and you want to nullify the pointers, change an attribute of the element
3. Catch the mutation with `mutations.forEach(function(mutation)` and nullify your array.

But eitherway, I don't think you should try to "guess" when to nullify the pointers. Calling an asynchronous function means you don't know when it will be done, by definition.

Hope it helps

Comment: If you can inject an "attribute change in a hidden DOM element" into the asynchronous code, you could as well inject a callback invocation. Much simpler and cross-browser-safe.

Comment: yes you are right, there are other ways, certainly much cleaner (but as I said, this idea is fun). But using a callback invocation would not be using the regular event stack. MutationObserver does.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're getting at, though I'm not sure what a separate stack frame would be necessary for. Apart from the fun.

Comment: @Bergi there's not much difference at the end. I just like the philosophy of saying "I'm done!" and then waiting for the cleaner to come, compared to saying "I'm done, now come!". Hard to explain... Calling directly a callback relates directly the 2 processes, even though it is async. Setting a flag to true and waiting for garbage collector is different. But you're right, fondamentally the effect is the same.